# .bat Replace a char in a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace

I need to loop through a list of text files, and rewrite them inserting a part of their name in one of the first lines, like:

Original file name: 101f.htm

Original file content:

```
Line1
Line2
.
.
LineN
```

New file name: 101f_.htm

New file content:

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> 
</head> 
<tr> 
Paciente Matricula: 101
</tr> 

Line1
Line2
.
.
LineN
```

I achieved some result with this .bat script:

```
set NOME=%%~ni_.xls
set MTR=%%~ni
for /R c:\teste\teste %%i IN (*.htm) DO (
ECHO.^<head^> > %NOME%
ECHO.^<meta http-equiv^="Content-Type" content^="text/html;charset=utf-8"^> >> %NOME%
ECHO.^</head^> >> %NOME%
ECHO.^<tr^> >> %NOME%
ECHO.Paciente Matricula: %MTR% >> %NOME%
ECHO.^</tr^> >> %NOME%
ECHO. >> %NOME%
type %%~nxi >> %NOME%
PAUSE
)
```

It gives me all I need, except by the line:

"Paciente Matricula: 101f"

I need to remove that "f" to the line display like:

"Paciente Matricula: 101"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code example:

```
@echo on &setlocal
for /R "c:\teste\teste" %%i IN (*f.htm) DO (
    (
    set "NOME=%%~ni_.xls"
    set "MTR=%%~ni"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    ECHO(^<head^> 
    ECHO(^<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"^>
    ECHO(^</head^>
    ECHO(^<tr^>
    ECHO(Paciente Matricula: !MTR:~0,-1!
    ECHO(^</tr^>
    ECHO(
    type "%%~nxi"
    )>"!NOME!"
    endlocal
)
```

Inside a codeblock (in the `for` loop from the first to the last parenthesis) you can't access `%` variables with changing values (`%NOME%`), there you must use `delayed expansion` and `!` variables (`!NOME!`).

Comment: Using setlocal enabledelayedexpansion and !MTR! solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Endoro's answer, using the following replace syntax works:

```
set MTR=%%~ni
set MTR=!MTR:f=!
```

I used this sintax because the I can not grant the "f" character will be the last one, it can be followed by a space.

The script below works for the task.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set NOME=%%~ni_.xls
for /R c:\teste\teste %%i IN (*.htm) DO (
set MTR=%%~ni
set MTR=!MTR:f=!
ECHO.^<head^> > %NOME%
ECHO.^<meta http-equiv^="Content-Type" content^="text/html;charset=utf-8"^> >> %NOME%
ECHO.^</head^> >> %NOME%
ECHO.^<tr^> >> %NOME%
ECHO.Paciente Matricula: !MTR! >> %NOME%
ECHO.^</tr^> >> %NOME%
ECHO. >> %NOME%
type %%~nxi >> %NOME%
)
```

Comment: You should use Endoro's way to use a block for the output and redirect the complete block only once to a file, as your way will append to each line a space